# Confluent CLI commands to fetch offset and consumer group details

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

Hi I am looking for a confluent cli command to use GetOffsetShell to get the earliest and latest offsets and to get consumer group details.

Looking for **Confluent cli commands for below kafka commands,**

**Fetching offset details**

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
    --broker-list localhost:9092 \
    --topic my_topic \
    --time -1
```

**Fetching list of consumer group**

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
```

**Describe consumer group**

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe group <group_name>
```

Can someone help me in getting these commands functionality using confluent cli commands?

Answer (score 0):

The Confluent Cloud CLI `ccloud` is not a replacement for those Kafka CLI commands and `confluent` command is for managing a local temp cluster of the platform.

You should still use `kafka-run-class` with any Kafka installation, hosted or otherwise. You may need to pass options such as `--command-config` or other properties for authentication purposes, however